# MySQL query not returning all records

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables in my database and am using left outer joins to join the tables and perform a query. The problem is that, not all of the matching records are returned, the first one always gets skipped out from the results for some reason.

Here's the link to the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da28/1),

*Schema + Test data:*

```
mysql> select * from main;
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+
| username | date       | water_quantity | water_chilled | smoked_what | smoke_count | sleep_duration | study_duration | screen_duration | loud_level | heat_level | humidity_level | stress_physical | stress_mental | stress_notes             | menstruation |
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 |              1 | no            | cigarettes  |          20 |            480 |              0 |             420 |          2 |          7 |              7 |               6 |             4 | Roamed a lot on the bike | no           |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 |              2 | no            | cigarettes  |          12 |            300 |              0 |               0 |          1 |          1 |              1 |               6 |             3 | met friends              | no           |
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from food;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| username | date       | food         |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | rice         |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | pizza        |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | french fries |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | burger       |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | naan         |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | fried rice   |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | lemon juice  |
+----------+------------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from alcohol;
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| username | date       | alcohol_type | alcohol_quantity |
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | beer         |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | beer_ale     |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | absinthe     |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | rum          |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | tequila      |                0 |
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from headache;
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| username | date       | intensity | duration | notes               |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 |         6 |       12 | something something |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from headache_areas;
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| username | date       | area            |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | left_temple     |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | right_temple    |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | behind_left_ear |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from headache_symptoms;
+----------+------------+-----------+
| username | date       | symptoms  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | aura      |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | vertigo   |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | dizziness |
+----------+------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from alcohol;
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| username | date       | alcohol_type | alcohol_quantity |
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | beer         |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | beer_ale     |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-16 | absinthe     |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | rum          |                0 |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | tequila      |                0 |
+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from drugs;
+----------+------------+----------+
| username | date       | drug     |
+----------+------------+----------+
| test     | 2012-08-21 | crocin   |
| test     | 2012-08-21 | azithral |
| test     | 2012-08-21 | crocin   |
| test     | 2012-08-21 | azithral |
| test     | 2012-08-21 | crocin   |
| test     | 2012-08-21 | azithral |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | ching    |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | chong    |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | blah1    |
| test123  | 2012-09-13 | blurg2   |
+----------+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Query I tried with the result:*

```
mysql> SELECT m.*,
    ->                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.food SEPARATOR ',') AS food, 
    ->                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.alcohol_type SEPARATOR ',') AS alcohol,
    ->                 a.alcohol_quantity,
    ->                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.drug SEPARATOR ',') AS drug,
    ->                 h.intensity AS headache_intensity,
    ->                 h.duration AS headache_duration,
    ->                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ha.area) AS headache_areas,
    ->                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT hs.symptoms) AS headache_symptoms,
    ->                 h.notes AS headache_notes
    ->             FROM main AS m 
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN food AS f ON f.username = m.username AND f.date = m.date 
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN headache AS h ON h.username = m.username AND h.date = m.date
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN headache_symptoms AS hs ON hs.username = m.username AND hs.date = m.date
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN headache_areas AS ha ON ha.username = m.username AND ha.date = m.date
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN drugs AS d ON d.username = m.username AND d.date = m.date
    ->                 LEFT OUTER JOIN alcohol AS a ON a.username = m.username AND a.date = m.date
    ->            ;
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| username | date       | water_quantity | water_chilled | smoked_what | smoke_count | sleep_duration | study_duration | screen_duration | loud_level | heat_level | humidity_level | stress_physical | stress_mental | stress_notes             | menstruation | food                                                       | alcohol                            | alcohol_quantity | drug                     | headache_intensity | headache_duration | headache_areas                           | headache_symptoms      | headache_notes      |
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| test123  | 2012-09-16 |              1 | no            | cigarettes  |          20 |            480 |              0 |             420 |          2 |          7 |              7 |               6 |             4 | Roamed a lot on the bike | no           | rice,pizza,french fries,burger,naan,fried rice,lemon juice | beer,beer_ale,absinthe,rum,tequila |                0 | ching,chong,blah1,blurg2 |                  6 |                12 | left_temple,right_temple,behind_left_ear | aura,vertigo,dizziness | something something |
+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It doesn't show me the other record in the table. Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because both rows have the same value for username. Try changing the username to be different. Your query is only looking at distinct usernames.

Comment: In your sqlfiddler you entered `'123-01-01 00:00:00'` as username in `main`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a54/7 (same with `food`)

Comment: please post the new link (fiddler links change when you change the input)

Comment: @alfasin Sorry, didn't know that, updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It outputs exactly what you "asked it" to do (by using `group concat`):

```
USERNAME    |...| FOOD                                                       | ALCOHOL  ...
+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
test123     |...| rice,pizza,french fries,burger,naan,fried rice,lemon juice |  beer,beer_ale,absinthe,rum,tequila  ...
```

When you use `group concat` it concatenates all the values of the `grouped` column into one output field.

**Update:**
I think I know understand what you're trying to achieve, since it's the same username in both records of table `main` it'll show as one column, to solve that you need to find the first field which is not identical for these two records - which is `date`. So all you have to do is add `GROUP BY m.username, date` to the [*end of your query*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da28/22).

Comment: But I need all the records in the main table, and there are two records in `main` and the other tables are getting `GROUP_CONCAT` which is the expected result, but it should show two records with food, alcohol, drugs, headache_areas and headache_symptoms `group_concat`

Comment: @nitstorm: Right, but since you `join` by `username` and both records have the same username, you get only one of them. What you want is probably this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da28/22

Comment: Could you please add this comment in the answer so that I can accept it? Thanks :)